# In MVC Who is Responsible for Animations?

Tags: model-view-controller, animation, architecture

This question is about a Cocoa app I'm working on but it could apply to anything using an MVC or related architecture.

Who is responsible for animations?

I can see two arguments:

1) Animation code should exist in a view (part of a view's presentation, how it draws itself) but be controlled by a controller (interpreting user input, etc).

2) Animations and their lifecycle should be managed completely by a controller and act on the views belonging to that controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first option is better because it would be fast if we can handle the events at view itself. Animation is most of the cases do not need additional data...so there is no need to reach to controller.

Comment: I don't disagree with you necessarily but doesn't "we can handle the events at view itself" violate our "dumb view" model? I've come to think of a view as a stick puppet minus the sticks. Of course my mental model might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think an animation is a modification of the model which is shown by the view. That's why I see the animation handling in the controller.